# Use a DRY function instead of a repeating ng-class for conditional text in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using over 5 times (and I am planning to use more) the same html/angular tag:

```
<div
    ng-class="{
      'critical': 'fa fa-warning fa-fw fa-2x text-red',
      'high': 'fa fa-warning fa-2x fa-fw text-orange' ,
      'medium': 'fa fa-warning fa-2x fa-fw text-yellow',
      'low': 'fa fa-warning fa-2x fa-fw text-aqua'
      }[ticket.service_impact]">
</div>
```

How can I use this ugly chunk of code in a filter or directive again and again in my code ? I am working on Rails so following DRY practises matters very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AngularJS Api Docs, you have some freedom regarding the expression part of the `ngClass` directive.

(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The directive operates in three different ways, depending on which of
>   three types the expression evaluates to:
>
> If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or
>   more space-delimited class names.
>
> If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair
>   of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a
>   class name.
>
> If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array
>   should either be a string as in type 1 or an object as in type 2. This
>   means that you can mix strings and objects together in an array to
>   give you more control over what CSS classes appear. See the code below
>   for an example of this.

So you could extract the lengthy expression and put it into a variable or function if you wish to do so.

Comment: It won't be either nice to flood the controller with these chunks of code (I've got many of them, my app is pretty visual). I would rather prefer to create a separate filter or directive for it.

Comment: Very true, but at least it would make changes to the chunks a lot easier, as you could change all usages of the chunk at once.